# Deleting Multiple Lines From a Text File

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I have done some research into this and what I have found so far is that I need to read the file into memory, line by line as this file will be eventually quite large, check for the string I don't want and continue reading/writing from there.

My program searches through the text file by date, reading the lines below the date and stopping when it reaches "end". I need to be able to delete one table from the date down to the "end" and replace it with another table in the same format which is stored in a dictionary.

Here is what I have so far.

This is the text file:

```
05/11/18
test1 N/A N/A N/A N/A N/A N/A N/A N/A N/A N/A
test2 N/A N/A N/A N/A N/A N/A N/A N/A N/A N/A 
test3 N/A N/A N/A N/A N/A N/A N/A N/A N/A N/A 
test4 N/A N/A N/A N/A N/A N/A N/A N/A N/A N/A 
end

06/11/18
test1 N/A N/A 09:30 18:00 09:30 18:00 09:30 18:00 09:30 18:00
test2 08:30 18:00 10:30 18:00 10:30 18:00 10:30 18:00 10:30 18:00
test3 09:30 18:00 07:30 18:00 07:30 18:00 07:30 18:00 07:30 18:00
test4 10:30 18:00 08:30 18:00 08:30 18:00 08:30 18:00 08:30 18:00
end
```

This is the dictionary with the new table:

```
  {'test1': ['N/A', 'N/A', '09:30', '18:00', '09:30', '18:00', '09:30', '18:00', '09:30', '18:00'], 
'test2': ['08:30', '18:00', '10:30', '18:00', '10:30', '18:00', '10:30', '18:00', '10:30', '18:00'], 
'test3': ['09:30', '18:00', '07:30', '18:00', '07:30', '18:00', '07:30', '18:00', '07:30', '18:00'], 
'test4': ['10:30', '18:00', '08:30', '18:00', '08:30', '18:00', '08:30', '18:00', '08:30', '18:00']}
```

By the way, I am trying to replace the table with the date 05/11/18.

This is the code for reading each line in the file and finding the line that starts with the date.

```
received="05/11/18"
with open("StaffTimes.txt","r+") as file:
    new_f=file.readlines()
    file.seek(0) #Puts pointer to start of file
    for line in new_f: #For every line in the file

        if received not in line: #If the date is not in the line
            file.write(line) #Re-write the line into the file

        if received in line:
            while True:
                nextLine=next(file, "").strip() #Stores the next line in nextLine
                if nextLine=="end": #Loops until end is found
                    next(file, "") #Now pointer is at line after end
                    break
```

This is the code for writing the dictionary back into text. (This isn't the problem, just providing it for context).

```
file.write(received)
    file.write("\n")
    usernameList=["test1", "test2", "test3", "test4"] #This will be received from client
    for username in usernameList:
        file.write(username)
        file.write(" ")
        workTimes=times.get(username)
        for time in workTimes:
            file.write(time)
            file.write(" ")
        file.write("\n")
    file.write("end")
    file.write("\n")
    file.write("\n")
```

Overall, my problem is I can only seem to get it to delete the date and nothing below it. It also just re-writes the whole thing anyway including the new table with and without the date.

I need the text file to look like this after it has been re-written:

```
05/11/18
test1 N/A N/A 09:30 18:00 09:30 18:00 09:30 18:00 09:30 18:00 
test2 08:30 18:00 10:30 18:00 10:30 18:00 10:30 18:00 10:30 18:00 
test3 09:30 18:00 07:30 18:00 07:30 18:00 07:30 18:00 07:30 18:00 
test4 10:30 18:00 08:30 18:00 08:30 18:00 08:30 18:00 08:30 18:00 
end

06/11/18
test1 N/A N/A 09:30 18:00 09:30 18:00 09:30 18:00 09:30 18:00
test2 08:30 18:00 10:30 18:00 10:30 18:00 10:30 18:00 10:30 18:00
test3 09:30 18:00 07:30 18:00 07:30 18:00 07:30 18:00 07:30 18:00
test4 10:30 18:00 08:30 18:00 08:30 18:00 08:30 18:00 08:30 18:00
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You read the file till you find the date you look for

  - until you do you simlpy copy lines over (including the one with the looked for date) through to a second file.
- If you hit the date, skip passing lines through until you find next end (use a bool).
- Write the new data and the "end" into the new file, reset the bool and continue

### Testfile-creation:

```
t = """ Some other data

05/11/18 
test1 N/A N/A N/A N/A N/A N/A N/A N/A N/A N/A 
test2 N/A N/A N/A N/A N/A N/A N/A N/A N/A N/A  
test3 N/A N/A N/A N/A N/A N/A N/A N/A N/A N/A  
test4 N/A N/A N/A N/A N/A N/A N/A N/A N/A N/A  
end

06/11/18 
test1 N/A N/A 09:30 18:00 09:30 18:00 09:30 18:00 09:30 18:00 
test2 08:30 18:00 10:30 18:00 10:30 18:00 10:30 18:00 10:30 18:00 
test3 09:30 18:00 07:30 18:00 07:30 18:00 07:30 18:00 07:30 18:00 
test4 10:30 18:00 08:30 18:00 08:30 18:00 08:30 18:00 08:30 18:00 
end"""

with open ("file.txt","w") as f: 
    f.write(t)
```

### Code to read and write new file:

```
look_for ="05/11/18"     
data = { 'test1': ['N/A', 'N/A', '09:30', '18:00', '09:30', '18:00', '09:30', '18:00', '09:30', '18:00'],  
'test2': ['08:30', '18:00', '10:30', '18:00', '10:30', '18:00', '10:30', '18:00', '10:30', '18:00'],  
'test3': ['09:30', '18:00', '07:30', '18:00', '07:30', '18:00', '07:30', '18:00', '07:30', '18:00'],  
'test4': ['10:30', '18:00', '08:30', '18:00', '08:30', '18:00', '08:30', '18:00', '08:30', '18:00']}

with open("file.txt","r") as f, open("file_2.txt","w") as f_new:
    # remember if we found it
    found_it = False
    for line in f.readlines():

        # handles the case we are currently in the region we need to skip lines till end
        if found_it:
            if line.startswith("end"):
                found_it = False

                # write replacement data and add end
                for k in data:
                    f_new.write(' '.join( [k] + data[k] +["\n"] ) )
                f_new.write(line) # add the end

            else:

                # found it but still reading its data: 
                # skip line from output
                continue

        # not in the critical region, just transfer lines
        if not line.startswith( look_for ):
            f_new.write(line)
            continue
        else:
            found_it = True
            f_new.write(line) # still need the date
```

### Testcode:

```
with  open("file_2.txt","r") as f:
    print(f.read())
```

Output:

```
Some other data

05/11/18
test1 N/A N/A 09:30 18:00 09:30 18:00 09:30 18:00 09:30 18:00 
test2 08:30 18:00 10:30 18:00 10:30 18:00 10:30 18:00 10:30 18:00 
test3 09:30 18:00 07:30 18:00 07:30 18:00 07:30 18:00 07:30 18:00 
test4 10:30 18:00 08:30 18:00 08:30 18:00 08:30 18:00 08:30 18:00 
end
end

06/11/18
test1 N/A N/A 09:30 18:00 09:30 18:00 09:30 18:00 09:30 18:00
test2 08:30 18:00 10:30 18:00 10:30 18:00 10:30 18:00 10:30 18:00
test3 09:30 18:00 07:30 18:00 07:30 18:00 07:30 18:00 07:30 18:00
test4 10:30 18:00 08:30 18:00 08:30 18:00 08:30 18:00 08:30 18:00
end
```

Rename new file to old file & have fun.

Comment: From a quick run this seems to do the trick. I will integrate it fully tomorrow and get back to the thread. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

maybe a better approach would be:

```
old_file = open("/path/to/old_file.txt", "r")
new_file = open("/path/to/new_file.txt", "w")

for line in old_file:
    if received in line:
        write_replacement_lines_to_new_file()

        # now skip lines in old_file until we get to the "end" marker.
        # the "for" loop will continue reading from the current
        # position in old_file
        for line in old_file: 
            if "end" in line:
                break

    else:
        new_file.write(line)

old_file.close()
new_file.close()
```

Then at the end, just copy new_file over the old_file (maybe with `os.rename()`)

Comment: you could just use the builtin `fileinput` module ... but i dont think this is quite what he is asking for

Comment: This would work if I only needed to get rid of the date line but the file would still re-write the lines beneath the date which are the ones I also need to get rid of. I need the code to recognise it has found the date, ignore the next x amount of lines until it sees end, continue writing until done then add back the new table. This could also be done by adding the new table first then re-writing the rest. Is there anyway to increment the line the for loop is looking at to move past the "end"?

Answer (score 0):

first make simple iterator that gives you each chunk

```
def iter_dates_in_file(filehandle_in):
  for line in filehandle_in:
     if re.match("\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{2,4}",line.strip()):
        matched = [line]
        while not matched[-1].strip() == "end":
          matched.append(next(filehandle_in))
        yield ''.join(matched)
```

then you can just test each chunk

```
with open(infile_name,"r") as in_file, open('output.txt','w') as f_out:
   for chunk in iter_dates_in_file(in_file):
       if test_if_i_should_save(chunk):
          f_out.write(chunk)
```

Comment: I will also try this method tomorrow and get back to you, thanks for the help.